# Highscore excerpt (10 better, 10 worse scores) in a single SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**Database schema:**
User(id, name)
Highscore(id, points, user_id)

When a User has submitted his highscore, I want him to see the 10 better and 10 worse highscores (to display his placement). Is it possible to accomplish this in a single SQL / ActiveModel query?

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
Highscore.where("points < ?", highscore.points).order(points: :desc).limit(10).merge(Highscore.where("points >= ?", highscore.points).order(:points).limit(10))
```

but `merge` does something else than I thought it did. So this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing merge or multiple where calls will `AND` the conditions together.  I haven't had any luck getting `UNION` to work in ActiveRecord, but you can get the same result with subqueries and Arel.

It would look something like this:

```
highscores = Highscore.arel_table
bottom_scores_query = Highscore.select(:id).where('points < ?', highscore.points).order(points: :desc).limit(10).to_sql
top_scores_query = Highscore.select(:id).where("points >= ?", highscore.points).order(:points).limit(10).to_sql

Highscore.where(highscores[:id].in(Arel.sql(bottom_scores_query)).or(highscores[:id].in(Arel.sql(top_scores_query)))
```

This solution uses Arel to do two subqueries to get the high scores where the id is in the top 10 high scores, or where the id is in the bottom 10 high scores.

Refactored into scopes, this would look something like:

```
class Highscore < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :top_scores, ->(highscore) { where("points >= ?", highscore.points).order(:points).limit(10) }
  scope :bottom_scores, ->(highscore) { where('points < ?', highscore.points).order(points: :desc).limit(10) }

  scope :summarized, ->(highscore) {
    top_scores_query = top_scores(highscore).select(:id).to_sql
    bottom_scores_query = bottom_scores(highscore).select(:id).to_sql

    where(arel_table[:id].in(Arel.sql(bottom_scores_query)).or(arel_table[:id].in(Arel.sql(top_scores_query))))
  }
end
```

And then you could get them by calling `Highscore.summarized(highscore)`.

Comment: What does the `Arel.sql` do?

Comment: `Arel.sql` returns an `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral`, which, when visited during SQL generation, will not be quoted or escaped or otherwise coerced into a value.  Without it above, the value inside of the calls to `in` would be coerced to `0`.